# Create a rule based on specific URL being visited

Tags: rules

I have set up a rule on my website so that when a content writer creates an article, it sends me an email notification and also the body content of the node so I can review it. Only after I have reviewed it and changed a field on the node to mark it as reviewed will it be published.
I often get the email on my smartphone and want a quick way to email back the site so automatically publish the article. Does anyone know what rule would do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

[Publish content](https://drupal.org/project/publishcontent)

> Exposes publish/unpublish links to your views, making it easy to
>   streamline workflows for reviewers, editors and publishers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. While this is an interesting module, I want a system whereby I reply to the email notification and that reply in itself is enough to trigger the article in question to be published. I don't want to have to login to the website here, more that the CMS sees the response URL and triggers the publish somehow.

Comment: You can just mail yourself publish link , which on click will publish the node